# Histogram, Density Plot, Quantile Line

Tags: r, histogram, density-plot

I have a return series, I have plotted the histogram but I need to add the density curve and 0.05 quantile line to this. How can I do this simply?

My histogram code:

```
ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Returns)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white")
```

What I tried in order to add the quantile line:

```
quantile <- quantile(Returns, prob = 0.05)

ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Returns)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=quantile), color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## Quantile line

`geom_vline(xintercept=quantile, color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)`

## Density

`geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(fill=NA, colour="royalblue")`

Hope it helps

Comment: This gives me the density plot, but my y axis values now get overlayed by density values. How do I make sure y axis continues to correspond to frequency (which was the case when I was plotting just the histogram)

Comment: just switch from ..density.. to ..count..: `geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), fill=NA, colour="royalblue")`

obs: this will work because your binwidth is set to 1. If it was set to x, you'd must pass `y = ..count..*x` to `geom_density()`